# Insert into table while ordering columns based on target table

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I am working with 3 different systems and need to get data across. We use SAS in the middle and what I need it for is basically do a SELECT * from a GCP table, do several steps (like creating some CSVs and local data tables) and finally upload the whole table into an remote Oracle server.

My problem is that columns at origin are not in the same order as in the final Oracle table. One of the steps I do in SAS is collect the column names in order from the destination table and store it in a temp table.

Is there any way to use those columns stored in a table as a nested query maybe in an INSERT statement? My problem is that at origin columns can be added at any time but at the destination (where those columns would be already be added) will most likely be in a different order.

I am trying to do something like this (not actually working SQL):

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
    SELECT 
        (SELECT * FROM temp_columns_table)
    FROM original_table
```

This would be instead of the normal:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3
    FROM original_table
```

The reason for this is that changes could be made fairly quickly without having to edit the SAS files to add a new column which could take up to a week to hit the production servers. If I manage to do something like this, I could add a new column in a couple hours.

Thanks in advance!

Besides trying something like above, I've tried "casting" the column names after a SELECT and using that also to explicitly declare column names at the INSERT. Nothings works.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you shouldn't be looking for any kind of *shortcuts*.

From your perspective, the most boring and the least *desirable* way is - actually - the best way you could take.

```
insert into destination_table
  (id, name, address, whatever)
select id, name, address, whatever
  from original_table;
```

Anything else just calls for errors and wrongly imported data. Although wildcards are *nice* to quickly do some operations, I wouldn't recommend you use them in production. There's no guarantee that column order will always match across three (!) systems.

Imagine simple example: you have to add `city` and `country` into the table. Though, as you don't have access to the 1st system, developer - who is allowed to do that - will inform you that they did it. "Cool", you'll say, "I'll add them too". But they didn't say that they added `country` first and `city` next.

With wildcard, `insert into target select * from source` will work OK as both city and country are *strings* and you'll end up with

- city = France
- country = Paris

---

Is there any way to do what you asked for? Probably. Oracle data dictionary contains column that says in which order columns have been added to the table; it is called `column_id`:

```
SQL> select column_name, data_type, column_id
  2  from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'DEPT'
  3  order by column_id;

COLUMN_NAM DATA_TYPE   COLUMN_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
DEPTNO     NUMBER              1
DNAME      VARCHAR2            2
LOC        VARCHAR2            3

SQL>
```

So, you could write code that extracts information from `user_tab_columns` and *dynamically* creates `insert` statement, e.g.

```
SQL> select 'insert into destination_table (' ||
  2    listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id) || ') ' ||
  3    'select ' ||
  4    listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id) ||
  5    ' from original_table' as stmt
  6  from user_tab_columns
  7  where table_name = 'DEPT';

STMT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into destination_table (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC) select DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC from original_table

SQL>
```

(or any of its derivates; PL/SQL included) but - once again - I wouldn't do it if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "column" you mean the variables then the order they appear in the dataset should have no impact with transferring data from SAS to Oracle.

Make a libref pointing to your Oracle schema and just use PROC APPEND and it will match the variables by their NAME.

```
libname myora oracle ..... ;
proc append base=myora.destination_table data=source_dataset force;
run;
```

If there is an extra variable in the SOURCE_DATASET then it will be ignored.  If there are "columns" in the target "table" that do not match any variable in the source dataset then their value will be missing (aka null).